# How to properly use $ for jQuery inside functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following ocde so I can use the $ short hand for jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){ ... }
```

But I also have a few functions outside it that require jQuery. How can I still use the $ short hand within those functions? It seems like $ won't work within my functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `$` outside of that `function` if you have another script on the page that uses `$` as their object. However, you can use [`noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to create an alias of `$` or `jQuery`.

```
(function($) {
    // Use $ here
})(jQuery);


// Create an alias of jQuery
var $_ = jQuery.noConflict();

// Use $_ here
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `jQuery` on the front and put after that:

```
(function($){
  ///
})(jQuery); // Use jQuery here
```

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `(function($){ /* code */ })(jQuery)`?